# Showing newsstand app as standalone app

Tags: ios6, newsstand-kit

Is there any way to show newsstand app not in the newsstand folder on ios device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is NO way in official iOS SDK to remove Newsstand apps from Newsstand folder. Though you can achieve it in jailbreak iOS.

You set UINewsstandapp to true for Newsstand apps in your application's plist file and they appear in Newsstand folder automatically. I think if you remove this key app should not show up in Newsstand folder (not sure(), but then you cannot call it as Newsstand app.

I dont think you should be able to set UIBackgroundModes to "newsstand-content" in case UINewsstandapp is false in your plist file. In short you cannot use background download functionality without setting UINewsstandapp to true in your app.